# Mongo db cursor count not working properly?

Tags: php, arrays, mongodb, php-mongodb

I have written following code in php and am using mongo db as database

```
$projection =  array("broadcast_id" => 1,"studentList" => 1);
$query = array('broadcast_id'=> $broadcast_id);
$count = $this->collection->find($query)->count();
$cursor = $this->collection->find($query,$projection);

$result = array();
foreach($cursor as $row)
{
    $idstring = trim($row["studentList"]);
    $idstring = preg_replace('/\.$/', '', $idstring);
    $idarray = explode('|', $idstring); 

    foreach($idarray as $studentId) 
    {      
        $this->StudentCollection = $this->db->studentTbl;
        $StudentCursor= $this->StudentCollection->find(array("student_id" => $studentId));

        if($StudentCursor->count() > 0)
        {
            foreach ($StudentCursor as $k => $srow) {
                array_push($result, $srow);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            array_push($result, array("datanotfound"=>1));
        }
    }
}    

return json_encode($result);
```

After fetching "studentList" from broadcastTbl table and `$idstring` has "5042|5043|5044" values which are student ids of studentTbl. Now I am trying to fetch corresponding students details by splitting them one by one on the basis of "|". After that I am trying to push them in array $result.

It always displays `$StudentCursor->count()` as "1" and never enter in else block even if find() query fails to find record and then it displays output as [] i.e it always stay in if statement !!!

Please help me in tracking out what is wrong in the code and writting it efficiently!!!

Comment: *"Also it always displays $StudentCursor->count() as "1" "*: where do you display it? (2) What are the values of `$studentId`? It would be more informative if you would assign the `$studentId` to the "datanotfound" key, so you would know for which student the query was made.

Comment: Have updated my question. sorry for inconvenience...

Comment: Would it be fair to assume `student_id ` is unique in studentTbl? When you `find` by unique id you cannot get more than 1 record by definition of uniqueness. Revise your logic here.

Comment: Thanks for the update, but none of my questions were really answered. Which is the student id *when* pushing "datanotfound"?